# Registrar solo si es un numero especifico en c++

Tags: c++

Buenas! estoy comenzando con C++ en Codebloks y me han dejado una tarea en la que me he quedado pegado:

Necesito que solo me registre los valores 1,2,3,4,5 y 10 de lo contrario que vuelva a solicitar el numero.

el ejercicio es un juego de dardos:

- Recibir los puntos de cada turno para su procesamiento. Únicamente puede aceptar los dígitos 10, 5, 4, 3, 2 y 1
- Procesar N cantidad de jugadores o rondas.
- Indicar si el jugador ganó un trago de cortesía con un mensaje. También debe imprimir el total de puntos de cada ronda.
- Antes de salir del programa, este debe imprimir el total de jugadores y el 
  promedio de puntos obtenidos.

El código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double turno1, turno2, turno3, turno4, turno5, promedio, jugador, jugadores =0, suma =0;
    int contador = 1;
    char continuar = 'c';

    cout << " \n";
    cout << "************************************************" << endl;
    cout << " \n";
    cout << "Restaurante La Sanguijuela Testaruda" << endl;
    cout << " \n";
    cout << "Programa calculador de lanzamientos" << endl;
    cout << " \n";
    cout << "************************************************" << endl;
    cout << " \n";

    cout << "Digite la cantidad de jugadores de la siguiente ronda: ";
        cin >> jugador;
        cout << " \n";

        do {

                cout << "Turno del jugador #" << contador << endl;
                cout << " \n";

                cout << "Cada jugador tiene el derecho de 5 turnos" << endl;
                cout << " \n";

                cout << "Recuerde que los puntajes validos son unicamente 10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1" << endl;
                cout << " \n";

                cout << "Si el jugador tiene un puntaje de 30 o mayor a 30 recibira una bebida GRATIS!" << endl;
                cout << " \n";

                cout << "Digite los puntos del primer turno: ";
                cin >> turno1;
                cout << " \n";

                cout << "Digite los puntos del segundo turno: ";
                cin >> turno2;
                cout << " \n";

                cout << "Digite los puntos del tercer turno: ";
                cin >> turno3;
                cout << " \n";

                cout << "Digite los puntos del cuarto turno: ";
                cin >> turno4;
                cout << " \n";

                cout << "Digite los puntos del quinto turno: ";
                cin >> turno5;
                cout << " \n";

                cout << "Cada jugador tiene derecho a 5 turnos" << endl;
                cout << " \n";

            suma = (turno1 + turno2 + turno3 + turno4 + turno5);

            if(suma >= 30) {
                cout << "Su puntuacion fue de: " << suma << " Puntos, usted gano una bebida de cortesia" << endl;
                cout << " \n";
            }

            else {
                cout << "Suerte para la proxima"<< endl;
                cout << " \n";
            }

            promedio = promedio + suma / jugador;

            } while ( ++contador <= jugador );

    cout << "Numero total de jugadores : " << jugador <<endl;
    cout << "Promedio de puntos obtenidos : " << promedio <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

debería quedar algo asi:
[image: deberia poder hacer los mismos procesos]

Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si en vez de introducir un entero, introduces texto u números decimales y falla cin, puedes detectar el error y limpiarlo con el siguiente código:

```
    if( cin.fail() ) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
    }
```

De no hacerlo el programa puede colgarse y llenarte la pantalla de basura.

```
int turno1;
do {
    cout << "Digite los puntos del primer turno: ";
    cin >> turno1;
    if( cin.fail() ) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
    }
    cout << " \n";
} while( ( turno1 < 1 ) || (  turno1 > 5 ) && (turno1 != 10)  );
```

Que al final me he animado y a ver que te parece esto

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int jugador, turno, suma;
    double promedio = 0.0;

    cout << " \n************************************************" << endl;
    cout << " \nRestaurante La Sanguijuela Testaruda" << endl;
    cout << " \nPrograma calculador de lanzamientos" << endl;
    cout << " \n************************************************" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Digite la cantidad de jugadores de la siguiente ronda: ";
    cin >> jugador;
    if( cin.fail() ) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        jugador = 1;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for( int i = 1; i <= jugador; ++i ) {
        cout << "Turno del jugador #" << i << endl;
        cout << " \n";

        cout << "Cada jugador tiene el derecho de 5 turnos" << endl;
        cout << " \n";

        cout << "Recuerde que los puntajes validos son unicamente 10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1" << endl;
        cout << " \n";

        cout << "Si el jugador tiene un puntaje de 30 o mayor a 30 recibira una bebida GRATIS!" << endl;
        cout << " \n";

        suma = 0;
        for( int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i ) {
            do {
                cout << "Digite los puntos del turno numero " << i << ": ";
                cin >> turno;
                if( cin.fail() ) {
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore();
                }
            } while( (turno < 1 ) || ( turno > 5 ) && ( turno != 10 ) );
            suma += turno;
        }

        if( suma >= 30 ) {
           cout << "Su puntuacion fue de: " << suma << " Puntos, usted gano una bebida de cortesia" << endl;
           cout << " \n";
        } else {
          cout << "Suerte para la proxima"<< endl;
          cout << " \n";
        }

        promedio += static_cast<double>(suma) / jugador;

    }

    cout << "Numero total de jugadores : " << jugador << endl;
    cout << "Promedio de puntos obtenidos : " << promedio << endl;

    cin >> turno; // Pausa
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Amigo mil gracias me has ayudado mucho con esto.

Comment: Amigo mil gracias me has ayudado mucho con esto. solo que hay programa aunque hace todos los turnos de los  jugadores, no los enumera, por ejemplo si le doy a 2 jugadores, me aparece, turno del jugador # 2 y los valores a introducir, en lugar de aparecer turno del Jugador # 1, la otra es que al introducir un numero fuera de los valores 1,2,3,4,5, y 10 deberá aparecer un mensaje de error y solicitar de nuevo el ingreso, de verdad amigo no sabes cuan agradecido estoy con la ayuda que me das.

Comment: Lo del jugador es una tontería, sólo hay que poner la variable i en vez de jugador, ya lo he cambiado. Y lo que falta estoy seguro que eres muy capaz de hacerlo tú solo. Un saludo.

Comment: @Ali-Rash si esta respuesta soluciona tu problema por favor, márcala como "_solución_". Muchas gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias @pipagerardo me ayudaste muchisimo, si lo de la variable lo solucione lo de los jugadores que faltaba no logre como hacerlo aun asi me saque 97 en la tarea, muchas gracias, intente enviarte un mensaje privado de agradecimiento pero no supe como, asi que lo hice por este medio, mil gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Primero, si trabajas con enteros, ¿Por qué usas `double` en vez de `int`?
 Entiendo que tiras un dado cinco veces valiendo el seis 10 puntos y si sacas más de 30 puntos tienes premio.

```
int turno1;
do {
    cout << "Digite los puntos del primer turno: ";
    cin >> turno1;
    cout << " \n";
} while( ( turno1 < 1 ) || (  turno1 > 5 ) && (turno1 != 10)  );
```

Esto repite el bloque hasta que el valor sea *1, 2, 3, 4, 5 o 10*.

Comment: Desde el móvil no me aclaro para poner código, gracias por editarlo.

Comment: En realidad no es un dado es un juego de dardos, mira:      El restaurante de don Pepe, "La Sanguijuela Testaruda" se encuentra en crisis. Sus clientes ya no son frecuentes y no consumen lo suficiente en el lugar. Don Pepe, al querer encontrar una solución, encuentra una vieja tabla de dardos y tiene una brillante idea: regalar bebidas a los mejores jugadores de dardos. La tabla de dardos tiene como valores 10, 5, 4, 3, 2 y 1